# unexpected 'end' fixing

Tags: ruby

Sometimes I get "unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end" error. 
Fixing of this problem is very boring so I wonder if there any trick to correct 'end' balance quickly and painlessly? Maybe autoformatting can be useful?

Comment: Proper indentation and code folding can help a lot here. Also will a decent editor will automatically insert `end`s for you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on an editor to fix your coding habits. If you have to change to a different system that doesn't support that editor you will be in a very bad position.

Instead, I have made it a habit to always close my blocks.

I immediately follow `{` with `}` then move my cursor inside. The same is true with `begin`/`end`, `do`/`end`, and double or single quotes, etc.

I code on Windows, Mac OS, and various flavors of Linux. I favor the Sublime Text Editor on my Macs, but write a huge amount of my code using vim on all the platforms. It's not the most friendly editor, but it's consistent across the platforms. With it, and the habits of automatically closing blocks, and quotes, I seldom run into that problem.